# StoreKit 2 Sandbox user subscriptions wrong productID issue

Tags: ios, storekit, storekittest

Strange behavior was found for subscription upgrades/downgrades for Sandbox users.

Step 1: Select from the internal app UI `productId.`

Step 2: Get the product from StoreKit by `Product.products(for: [productID])`

Step 3: Purchase fetched product: `product.purchase(options: [options])`

Step 4: Analyze the received `Product.PurchaseResult.`

And what we have here:
Works perfectly on the first try. The correct and successful transaction was received.
But when tried to change the subscription, using the same flow,  in Step 4 received a successful transaction with a different `productID.` Usually the previous subscription `productID.`

Can't get how it can be. Request purchase with one productID, but receive successful result with another.

Any ideas of what is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you upgrading or downgrading?  If you are downgrading then the higher level subscription continues until the renewal time is reached, at which point it will renew at the lower level. An upgrade is subscribed at the higher level immediately.

Comment: @Paulw11 I saw that behavior with upgrading also :( Trying to buy the top-level subscription but receive the lowest-level subscription productId in the success response.